# send data in another ViewController

Tags: objective-c, parsing, nsstring

I need to pass the class PassengerNavi data server Parse give authorized users. And then write the data to the NSString. And how to get data from PFUser I do not know, I really need help developers)

My ViewController.m file:

```
    #import <CloudKit/CloudKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "PassengerNavi.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "RegistrationConsole.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (IBAction)authorizationController:(id)sender {
    [PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:self.username.text
                                 password:self.password.text block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!error) {

             PassengerNavi *PassengerViewController = [[PassengerNavi alloc]initWithNibName:@"PassengerNavi" bundle:nil];
             [self presentViewController:PassengerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
         } else {
             UIAlertView *errorAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"British Airways" message:@"Your have Business Class ticket. Please use First Class ticket or contact with British Airways customer center." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
             [errorAlertView show];
         }
     }];
}

- (IBAction)registrationController:(id)sender {
    RegistrationConsole *RegistrationViewController = [[RegistrationConsole alloc]initWithNibName:@"RegistrationConsole" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:RegistrationViewController animated:nil completion:nil];
}

@end
```

My PassengerNavi.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface PassengerNavi ()

@end

@implementation PassengerNavi

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];

    PFQuery *test = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
    [test whereKey:@"google" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [test whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
    NSArray *arrayofObjectIds = [test findObjects];

    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
    [query whereKey:@"objectId" containedIn:arrayofObjectIds];
    NSArray *followingArray = [query findObjects];
    NSLog(@"%@",followingArray);

    self.clubWorldID = followingArray;

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ba_fc_wallpaper.jpg"]];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (IBAction)britishDialler:(id)sender {
    BACalling *CallerViewController = [[BACalling alloc]initWithNibName:@"BACalling" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:CallerViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (IBAction)britishMessenger:(id)sender {
    BAMessenger *MessengerViewController = [[BAMessenger alloc]initWithNibName:@"BAMessenger" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:MessengerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)personalProfileView:(id)sender {
    PersonalProfile *PersonalViewController = [[PersonalProfile alloc]initWithNibName:@"PersonalProfile" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:PersonalViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)aboutSoftwareView:(id)sender {
    AboutSoftware *AboutViewController = [[AboutSoftware alloc]initWithNibName:@"AboutSoftware" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:AboutViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

Comment: How are you presenting your second view controller?

Comment: This depends on how you segue to the 2nd viewController. Do you segue via a button action - connected on the storyboard? Or are you presenting the viewController via code within your class file?

Comment: There are so many tutorials available to pass data between view controllers. [Like this](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/torrey-betts/archive/2014/05/29/passing-data-between-view-controllers-ios-obj-c.aspx). No hard feelings but at least search before posting the question, it will be useful in future. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
SecondViewController *vc = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
vc.usernameObjectId      = // <-- however you store/produce the value in FirstViewController
```

After that, push/display/whatever `vc`.

***FYI:*** It's better to declare an `NSString` property as:
`@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *...`

Comment: How initialize this usernameObjectId in another class? May you can call me in FaceTime?

Comment: @Dmitriy That's a different question. You asked how to **pass** the information. If you need to know how to **generate** the data, ask a question about that.

Comment: When I open another ViewController I receive empty data

Comment: @Dmitriy You should ask another question for this issue.

Comment: call me please at FaceTime - groschovskiy@icloud.com. I show you my desktop. And maybe you know how to fix this issue.

Comment: @Dmitriy I'm sorry, but I'm not going to do that.